# CSS to change variable range of grid boxes

Tags: html, css

I would like to change the background color of the grid boxes based on what's selected in the dropdown, but I'm at a loss. If A/3 is selected, boxes 1-3 would change. If C/10 is selected, boxes 1-10 would change. This is my first web-development project, so I may be approaching this wrong. If so, please let me know. Thanks for any help!

```css
.menu
            {
             overflow: hidden;
             background-color: #29648A;
             margin:0 auto;
             }
          .dropdown
            {
             float: left;
             overflow: hidden;
             width: 25%;
             }
          .button
            {
             font-size: 16px;
             border: none;
             outline: none;
             color: white;
             padding: 10px 10px;
             background-color: inherit;
             width: 100%;
             text-align: center;
             }
          .dropdown:hover
            {
             background-color: #2E9CCA;
             }
          .list
            {
             display: none;
             position: absolute;
             background-color: #F9F9F9;
             box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
             width: 24.65%;
             }
          .list a
            {
             float: none;
             color: black;
             padding: 12px 16px;
             text-decoration: none;
             display: block;
             text-align: center;
             }
          .list a:hover
            {
             background-color: #ddd;
             }
          .dropdown:hover .list
            {
             display: block;
             }
          .wrapper
            {
             display: grid;
             grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
             grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 100px);
             grid-gap: 10px;
             max-width: 400px;
             margin: 50px auto;
             }
          .box
            {
             background-color: #AAABB8;
             color: white;
             text-align: left;
             font-size: 20px;
             padding: 10px 10px;
             border-radius: 5px;
             max-width: 100px;
             }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
      <head>
      </head>
    
      <body>
        <div class="menu">
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="button">A</button>
            <div class="list">
              <a href="#">1</a>
              <a href="#">2</a>
              <a href="#">3</a>
              <a href="#">4</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="button">B</button>
            <div class="list">
              <a href="#">5</a>
              <a href="#">6</a>
              <a href="#">7</a>
              <a href="#">8</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="button">C</button>
            <div class="list">
              <a href="#">9</a>
              <a href="#">10</a>
              <a href="#">11</a>
              <a href="#">12</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="button">D</button>
            <div class="list">
              <a href="#">13</a>
              <a href="#">14</a>
              <a href="#">15</a>
              <a href="#">16</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <section>
          <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="box">1</div>
            <div class="box">2</div>
            <div class="box">3</div>
            <div class="box">4</div>
            <div class="box">5</div>
            <div class="box">6</div>
            <div class="box">7</div>
            <div class="box">8</div>
            <div class="box">9</div>
            <div class="box">10</div>
            <div class="box">11</div>
            <div class="box">12</div>
            <div class="box">13</div>
            <div class="box">14</div>
            <div class="box">15</div>
            <div class="box">16</div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I see you need to add some javascript code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) & [removeClass()](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)  using jquery
Add some if statements with different id to each box and use that as a selector to connect each column to its own box!
Give it a try and I can help if needed.

Comment: Ahh very nice. I appreciate it! Like I said, I'm new to this, but this sounds like just what I need. Thank you!